# Initializing std::unique_ptr with deleter

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is my code:

```
class dummy{
    public:
    int x;
dummy(int y):x(y){
}

};


const auto& zDeleter = [](dummy * obj){
    std::cout<<"this is called"<<std::endl;
    delete obj;
};


std::unique_ptr<dummy,decltype(zDeleter)> funct(){
    std::unique_ptr<dummy,decltype(zDeleter)> temp(new dummy(10),zDeleter);

    return temp;


}

int main(){

    std::unique_ptr<dummy,decltype(zDeleter)> get(nullptr,zDeleter);

    return 0;   

}
```

What i want to happen is to make `std::unique_ptr<dummy,decltype(zDeleter)> get` uninitialized and use it to get `funct()`'s return value. `get = funct();` gives me error.

I tried doing `std::unique_ptr<dummy,decltype(zDeleter)> get;` but i get `tuple` "recursively required" error. I get no error if i compile with `std::unique_ptr<dummy,decltype(zDeleter)> get(nullptr,zDeleter);` but it won't let me receive `funct()` 's return value. Odd question but i am doing this for research purposes.

Bonus question: how come it get long errors if i will use `auto&& zDeleter` instead of `auto zDeleter` or `const auto& zDeleter` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decltype(zDeleter)` is const. `std::unique_ptr<dummy,decltype(zDeleter)> get;` won't work because you need provide a value for your deleter, since it's a const member.

And because you deleter function has const modifier, so you can't use assignment.

Why don't you do like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<dummy,decltype(zDeleter)> get = funct();
```

or if you replace `delctype(zDeleter)` with `std::function<void(dummy*)>`, it will work

Comment: Yeah that works but i am trying to see if i can delay the initialization(out of curiousity). Because i get no errors if i will use `std::unique_ptr<dummy> test;`. I get the feeling that it's because of `decltype` but i can't syntax it properly.

Comment: So what do you mean by "it won't let me receive funct() 's return value."

Comment: Something like this, let me edit my question. `get = funct();`

Comment: That's because `decltype(zDeleter) ` is a const type

Comment: oooo i see let me try

Comment: nope, still the same error even if i change to ` auto zDeleter`

Comment: You mentioned tuple "recursively required" error, but I don't see any tuples in your code.